# Do RPM Requires(post) dependencies imply normal Requires? If so why aren't they listed in --whatrequires?

Tags: rpm

I have two RPM's, `aaa` and `bbb`.

Suppose `aaa` is built with this dependency:

```
Requires(post): bbb
```

Is `Requires(post)` a *superset* of `Requires`, meaning it is like `Requires` but with an additional ordering requirement, or does it only require that `bbb` be installed during `aaa`'s `%post` script but not necessarily thereafter?

I always thought it was the first option, but the actual behavior of `rpm` seems to imply the second option:

```bash
$ rpm -q aaa bbb
aaa-1.0.0-1.noarch
bbb-1.0.0-1.noarch
$ rpm -qR aaa
bbb
$ rpm -q --whatrequires bbb
$ rpm -e --test bbb
$ echo $?
0
```

**Question:** what are the semantics of `Requires(post)` as compared to `Requires`?

Answer (score 0):

OK looks like I found the answer, which is that `Requires(post)` has no effect once the `%post` script is started.

Quoting [max-rpm](http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-depend-manual-dependencies.html):

```
Requires(X): foo
              
Here, X can be one of pre, post, preun, or postun, which tells RPM that
the package depends on package foo for running the corresponding %pre,
%post, %preun, or %postun script.

In practice, RPM enforces the above dependencies until the specified
script has been run, not at that time. In other words, it will allow
erasing a dependency that was marked for eg. the %post script for an
already installed package, but will not allow erasing one that is
required for a %postun script for such a package. This is to reduce
confusion; it would be somewhat odd if RPM told one to install a package
in order to get another one erased.
```